# Plnkr - How to add curly brackets?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Basically I just got started using plnkr.co.
However every time I try to insert a "}" my HTML section gets crammed together as shown in the picture:
[image]

I simply click shift+alt+0 and it gets crammed together.

Anyone used to plnkr who can tell me what's happening here?

**EDIT: Seems like there's no way to change this.**

**Conclusion: The developers behind Plnkr are morons.**

Comment: Can you link to the plnkr?

Comment: Why you have to press `shift+alt+0` to add the curly brackets?

Comment: @ExplosionPills
Well there's really nothing to link to.
It happens on every plnkr edit I make - regardless of the browser.
I'd assume it's some sort of hotkeys in javascript - but it seems like an insanely idiotic implementation.

Comment: @runTarm
Keybindings vary from keyboard to keyboard you know. This is how I'd enter it one mine.
I'm pretty much looking for a way to disable the plnkr feature but I cannot find any way to do so.
Blows my mind why these guys would implement a feature like that and yet give no option of disabling it.

Answer (score 15):

> Conclusion: The developers behind Plnkr are morons.

There is no *they*, there is only me and I don't typically think of myself as a moron. If you found yourself on Plunker it is likely because there is a body of people who find it useful and worthwhile, warts and all. If this is the attitude you bring to the community then you may find more fertile ground elsewhere.

Have you considered that `SHIFT-ALT-0` might seem like a very unlikely key combination to be used by someone who programs and closes braces quite often? If that is the setup you choose then I'm sorry that I have not considered your particular situation. As runTarm pointed out, `SHIFT-ALT-0` is bound to the collapse command by default in the ace editor.

Perhaps a better conclusion would be that configurable keybindings would be a great feature.

Answer (score 2):

The `Alt+0` is a default shortcut for `fold all` in the [Ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) editor.

[Ace editor: Default Keyboard Shortcuts](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts)

And Plunker borrow the key-binding from Ace as a default too, so all the html tags are folded.

You could try changing the key-binding option to see if it help, it is under the Editor Options panel, the cog icon on the right

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the other keybindings but they have the same alt+0 binding. Thanks though.

I'm astonished that they'd include such inflexible key-bindings and provide no way to disable them. What a pity.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've experienced Plunker to be a bit laggy, but overall it could easily be one of my favorite JS online editors (ability to add files!).. except for this curly problem.

I'm using a danish keyboard, and unfortunately the curly braces are located on CTRL+ALT+7: { and CTRL+ALT+ 0: }. This means that whenever I make a }, everything collapses.

I'm using these online editors mostly for testing AngularJS, which means that there's a LOT of {{directives}} everywhere.

Switching between either ACE, EMACS or VIM didn't seem to solve the problem.